Method of Moment for Normal mixtures $p\cdot N(0, 1) + q\cdot N(\eta, 1)$
Setup
Let $X_1,\ldots , X_n$ be random variables according to
$$
p\cdot N(0, 1) + q\cdot N(\eta, 1),\ p\in (0, 1), q:=1-p.
$$
We use method of moments to obtain the needed starting $\sqrt{n}$-consistent estimators for $p$ and $\eta$.
Result
This is Lehmann's result: Lehmann, 1999, p.508

We find
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_i]=q\eta, \mathbb{E}[X^2_i]=p+q(\eta^2+1)=1+q\eta^2.
$$
The estiating equations for $q$ and $\eta$ are therefore
$$
q\eta = \bar{X}, q\eta^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i X^2_i - 1
$$
and the resulting estimators of $q$ and $\eta$ are
$$
\hat{\eta} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i X^2_i - 1}{\bar{X}},\\
\hat{q} = \frac{\bar{X}^2}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i X^2_i - 1}.
$$

What I think
Is the population moment calculation correct in the first place? My calculations yielded the following.
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_i] = q\eta, \mathbb{E}[X^2_i] = \mathbb{Var}[X_i] + (\mathbb{E}[X_i])^2 = (p^2 + q^2) + (q\eta)^2
$$
What is wrong?
As it stands, several pages of Lehmann's are misprints, which I find hard to believe...

If $Y_0 \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y_\eta \sim N(\eta,1)$ and the $X_i$ are iid with the mixture distribution (a probability $p$ of following $Y_0$'s distribution and a probability $q$ of following $Y_\eta$'s distribution) then

$\mathbb E[Y_0]=0, \mathbb E[Y_\eta]=\eta$, so $\mathbb E[X_i]=p\,0+q\eta=q\eta$
$\mathbb E[Y_0^2]=1, \mathbb E[Y_\eta^2]=1+\eta^2$, so $\mathbb E[X_i^2]=p\,1+q(1+\eta^2)=1+q\eta^2$

Your suggestion that $\mathbb{Var}[X_i] = (p^2 + q^2)$ is not correct; it is clearly always at least $1$ and exceeds $1$  when $\eta \not =0$. Simulate it to convince yourself.
It then seems a reasonable method-of-moments approach to solve $\bar X = \hat q\hat \eta$ and $\overline  {X^2} = 1+\hat q\hat \eta^2$ (using $\overline  {X^2}$ for $\frac1n\sum X_i^2)$ as simultaneous equations to give

$\dfrac{\left(\bar X\right)^2}{\overline  {X^2}-1}$ as an estimator of $q$ and so $1-\dfrac{\left(\bar X\right)^2}{\overline  {X^2}-1}$ as an estimator of $p$
$\dfrac{\overline  {X^2}-1}{\bar X}$ as an estimator of $\eta$

with the usual caveats over method-of-moments approaches:  in this case, estimates of $p$ and $q$ below $0$ and above $1$ are possible but would not then be plausible probabilities.
